# Parse multiple cells and values from a single JSON-request

Tags: json, excel, vba

I would like to display the following variables from a JSON-request; "time", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volumefrom", "volumeto" in respectively the following columns B, C, D, E, F, G and H.

The request: 
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

So, I would like to see for example the values of "open" located in C2:C51.

I wrote the following macro:

```
Sub OHLCdata()                                                            
Dim strURL As String                                                      
Dim strJSON As String                                                     
Dim strCurrency As String                                                 
Dim strLength As Integer                                                  
Dim i As Integer                                  
Dim http As Object                                                     

strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=" & strTicker & "&tsym=" & strCurrency & "&limit=" & strLength & "&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG" 
strTicker = Range("A2")
strCurrency = Range("A3")                                           
strLength = Range("A4")                                                   
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")                           
http.Open "GET", strURL, False                                      
http.Send                                                             
strJSON = http.responsetext                                               
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)                                 
i = 2                                                                     

For Each Item In JSON("DATA")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("time")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("open")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("high")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("low")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("close")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("volumefrom")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("volumeto")                              
i = i + 1                                                                
Next                                                                      
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the macro doesn't work as debugging shows that there is an error in the following line:

```
For Each Item In JSON("DATA")
```

However, I need to refer to ("Data") right?

```
{"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":true,**"Data"**:[{"time":1493769600,"close":1507.77,"high":1609.84,"low":1424.05,"open":1445.93,"volumefrom":338807.89999999997,"volumeto":523652428.9200001},
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Under `Tools/References` set the option to `Require Variable Declaration`.  At the beginning of your module, enter the line `Option Explicit`.  This will help you find other errors.  `Json.Converter` is not part of native VBA, so without more information, we can only make poor guesses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the following error message: "compile error: invalid inside procedure." Sorry about the lack of information. I downloaden the JsonConverter.bas from the following github: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas. In addition, I enabled Microsoft Scriptime Running. Any idea how I can improve the macro? Thank you!

Comment: What line shows the error?  There is nothing in your posted code that should do that.

Comment: Also, when you "downloaded" the file, did you really do that?  Or did you copy/paste from that page?

Comment: ALso you are using variables before you actually assign them a value: Move your `strURL` statement below the `strLength` Statement

Comment: I installed the JsonCOnverter Module and the Dictionary Class Module and ran your code (Using "ETH" as the symbol. My responsetext was valid JSON, but the jsonparser object did not return `DATA` as an object, but a string.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware   Examine the `Type` characteristics of `JSON` and also `item` to see what those strings represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?*

You are close:

1. I suspect you probably did a copy/paste on the JSON parser rather than downloading the `*.bas` file and importing it.  If you copied the file and then pasted it into a module, you would see the line `Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter"`  Although legal in the `.bas` file, it is not in a module, hence the *"compile error: invalid inside procedure." * error message.
2. You create `strURL` before you define the variables that are included. Therefore the variables will be blank
3. Your column numbers are off when you write the results, so it will start in column A instead of B.
4. You fail to declare some of your variables.
5. Since JSON is a dictionary type object, the key will be case sensitive (unless you declare it to be otherwise).  Hence `DATA` and `Data` are two different keys.  You need to use `Data`.

Here is your code with the changes; and don't forget to import the .bas file and don't copy/paste.

```
Option Explicit
Sub OHLCdata()
Dim strURL As String
Dim strJSON As String
Dim strCurrency As String
Dim strLength As Integer
Dim strTicker As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim http As Object

Dim JSON As Dictionary, Item As Dictionary


strTicker = Range("A2")
strCurrency = Range("A3")
strLength = Range("A4")

strURL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=" & strTicker & "&tsym=" & strCurrency & "&limit=" & strLength & "&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG"

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", strURL, False
http.Send
strJSON = http.responsetext
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)
i = 2

For Each Item In JSON("Data")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("time")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("open")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("high")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("low")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("close")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("volumefrom")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("volumeto")
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

**Note**: With regard to the `Attribute` line visible in the bas file if you open it in a text editor, you may refer to Chip Pearson's article on [Code Attributes For The VBA Object Browser](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CodeAttributes.aspx).  It is generally considered bad form to refer to an external link, as they may disappear.  However, I could not find a good discussion here on SO. If I have missed it, someone please comment and I will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

You may get JSON data into arrays and output as shown in the example code below. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OHLCdata()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG", False
        .send
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    vJSON = vJSON("Data")
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is the output for me:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).